# API response with custom response model to JSON and Map

Tags: java

I need help about getting an API response and mapping it into different maps.
I have an API:

```
public CustomResponse getAllInfoAPI(String Id) {
    String url = /.../
    ResponseEntity<CustomResponse> response = doCall(url, HttpMethod.GET, getAuthHeader(),
        null, CustomResponse.class);
    if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
      System.out.println(response.getBody());
      return response.getBody();
    } else {
      log.error(String.format(
          "An error occurred : %s",
          response.getBody()));
      throw new MyException());
    }
  }
```

And My CustomResponse Model is like this:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomResponse{

  private String id;
  private String date;
  private Author author;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  public static class Author{

    private String id;
    private String name;
  }
}
```

I am trying to get all customResponses by calling the API using this which is not completed and I need help about this:

```
public void getAllInfo() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    CustomResponse all_info = getAllInfoAPI("PR_12");
    Map<String, String> cInfo = new HashMap <>();
  
    //// HERE I DONT KNOW HOW TO COMPLETE THE CODE TO HAVE DIFFERENT MAPS BETWEEN 
    //// SOME OF THE CUSTOM RESPONSE'S KEYS NOT ALL OF THEM. FOR EXAMPLE ID AND AUTHOR NAME
  }
```

And what I want is to try to loop over it for **just one time** and extract different maps. For example, I want to create a map for all `customResponse id` and `author name`, and then I want to take author name by customResponse id parameter. I know I have to use `jackson library` but I am really confused and I really need a small example. I am a newbie and am sorry if it is a basic question. Could anyone help me with this?